# How can I connect a case power switch to these DeskMini X300M STX pins?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, pin, jumper, mini-stx

I am looking at an Asrock DeskMini X300M STX motherboard (images below; this form factor is often called Mini-STX). This board, produced to fit a very bespoke case, has a set of pins for the power switch, power led, reset switch, etc. - supposedly just like any other motherboard... except that these pins are much closer together than is regularly the case on a motherboard (and are perhaps narrower too).

That means that regular case connector terminals for these switches and LEDs just don't fit onto these pins.

My question: What can I do to make these pins connectible to a regular power switch jumper terminal? Are there plastic/metal parts compatible with these smaller pins, which I could get and use? Are there "female-to-male" individual pin adapter I might use? Some other idea perhaps? I want to avoid having to solder anything, naturally.

**Clarification:** I *know* the pin-out of the different pins; that's listed in the motherboard manual. The problem is not which pins to connect, it's the physical inability to use the regular jumper-like connectors with these pins.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is very likely this is one of the common *pitches*. You may even be able to find an off-the-shelf adapter. Most (full-sized) PC stuff uses 0.1 inch.

Comment: @DanielB: Can you perhaps help me with some search terms to use? And - it's not off-the-shelf in PC stores; what kind of store (physical or on-line) should I visit in order to look for something like this?

Answer (score 2):

As shown in [this guide](https://download.asrock.com/Manual/QIG/X300M-STX_multiQIG.pdf), there's a diagram for the connectors. You can use any button to connect the "PWRBTN" pins, for the power button to be triggered. Same goes for "RESET" pins.

PLED and HDLED are the processor's and HDD's LEDs ( so, no buttons needed, of course )

Edit:
There's an even better diagram:
[image]

Comment: I know what pin is used for what. The problem is that I _can't_ use the usual connectors which PC cases provide, since the pins are too close together. Please re-read the question.

Comment: @einsupportsModeratorStrike Oh. Sorry, then! But, are you sure they're smaller? They do look smaller than the F_Audio panel, but that's how they SHOULD be...

Comment: You could use something  like the cables attached here, if they fit. I don't know the name of the connector, but you can find them with the search term "UART". https://he.aliexpress.com/item/1005002919716645.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.80.464e586a3giyl8&gatewayAdapt=glo2isr

Comment: I'm sure because I physically checked with the power switch and power led connectors, otherwise I wouldn't have asked these questions... will follow your link and see.

Comment: @einsupportsModeratorStrike Just to make sure, I don't know if they will fit, but they might be. You could just use some shrink to attach bare cables, like here. Just heat it with a ligher for two seconds to shrink it. https://he.aliexpress.com/item/1005005087785893.html

Comment: Indeed, I already bought some cabling and shrinking-insulation, but I am really really hoping to avoid having to go that route.

Comment: I mean, if the computer won't be portable, you might be able to use ONLY shrink, without soldering.